# Есть bat файл который выполняет определенную задачу, в нем (в бат файле) надо прописать в конце команду, чтобы открылась папка которая указана в пути

Tags: windows, bat

Есть bat файл который выполняет определенную задачу, в нем (в бат файле) надо прописать в конце команду, чтобы открылась папка которая указана в пути... т.е выполняется команда и после открывается путь(который я указал в бат файле) в проводнике в отдельном окне. Внимание вопрос: что можно прописать? нужны команды. Спасибо заранее всем!

Comment: `explorer %directory%`

Comment: super! Thanks!!